# How to interpret the results of ADF test using SAS ARIMA?

Tags: interpretation, sas, unit-root

```
                                       The SAS System      14:11 Thursday, October 6, 2013   1

                                      The ARIMA Procedure

                                Name of Variable = ln_G_S_Index

                     Period(s) of Differencing                           1
                     Mean of Working Series                       0.094293
                     Standard Deviation                           0.316757
                     Number of Observations                             15
                     Observation(s) eliminated by differencing           1


                                        Autocorrelations

 Lag    Covariance    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1      Std Error

   0      0.100335        1.00000    |                    |********************|             0
   1     0.0026693        0.02660    |          .         |*        .          |      0.258199
   2     -0.018517        -.18456    |          .     ****|         .          |      0.258382
   3      0.029440        0.29342    |         .          |******    .         |      0.267025

                                 "." marks two standard errors


                                    Inverse Autocorrelations

               Lag    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

                 1       -0.14763    |          .      ***|         .          |
                 2        0.19526    |          .         |****     .          |
                 3       -0.27516    |          .   ******|         .          |


                                    Partial Autocorrelations

               Lag    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

                 1        0.02660    |          .         |*        .          |
                 2       -0.18539    |          .     ****|         .          |
                 3        0.31522    |          .         |******   .          |


                               Phillips-Perron Unit Root Tests

              Type           Lags         Rho    Pr < Rho        Tau    Pr < Tau

              Zero Mean         0    -11.6883      0.0066      -3.23      0.0033
                                1    -11.4504      0.0074      -3.23      0.0034
              Single Mean       0    -13.7527      0.0129      -3.71      0.0171
                                1    -12.6667      0.0218      -3.76      0.0157
              Trend             0    -14.5288      0.0601      -3.25      0.1144
                                1    -13.1531      0.1022      -3.20      0.1239
                                        The SAS System      14:11 Thursday, October 6, 2013   2

                                      The ARIMA Procedure

                                Name of Variable = ln_G_S_Index

                     Period(s) of Differencing                           1
                     Mean of Working Series                       0.094293
                     Standard Deviation                           0.316757
                     Number of Observations                             15
                     Observation(s) eliminated by differencing           1


                                        Autocorrelations

 Lag    Covariance    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1      Std Error

   0      0.100335        1.00000    |                    |********************|             0
   1     0.0026693        0.02660    |          .         |*        .          |      0.258199
   2     -0.018517        -.18456    |          .     ****|         .          |      0.258382
   3      0.029440        0.29342    |         .          |******    .         |      0.267025

                                 "." marks two standard errors


                                    Inverse Autocorrelations

               Lag    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

                 1       -0.14763    |          .      ***|         .          |
                 2        0.19526    |          .         |****     .          |
                 3       -0.27516    |          .   ******|         .          |


                                    Partial Autocorrelations

               Lag    Correlation    -1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1

                 1        0.02660    |          .         |*        .          |
                 2       -0.18539    |          .     ****|         .          |
                 3        0.31522    |          .         |******   .          |


                            Augmented Dickey-Fuller Unit Root Tests

    Type           Lags         Rho    Pr < Rho        Tau    Pr < Tau          F    Pr > F

    Zero Mean         0    -11.6883      0.0066      -3.23      0.0033
                      1    -12.4302      0.0041      -2.42      0.0197
    Single Mean       0    -13.7527      0.0129      -3.71      0.0171       6.91    0.0157
                      1    -25.2133      <.0001      -3.63      0.0214       6.59    0.0206
    Trend             0    -14.5288      0.0601      -3.25      0.1144       6.44    0.0799
                      1    -45.0252      <.0001      -3.20      0.1265       6.92    0.0622
                                        The SAS System      14:11 Thursday, October 6, 2013   3
```

Comment: It would help to report what you understand from this `PROC` and where you are stuck.

Comment: Since you have only 15 data points, there is not much you can interpret.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me any material for understanding the Result interpretation of  ADF Unit root test using SAS?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the ADF Unit Root Test section.

If your data is a random walk with drift, then it will be under the type 'Single Mean'.

For the ADF test, 
H0: Non-stationary
Ha: Stationary

if P-value < 0.05, you reject the null hypo (H0) and conclude that data series is stationary. It should be as you already differenced the data once.

Under 'Pr < Rho' which stands for the P-value of your Rho (autocorrelation), it is 0.0129 and <0.0001 thus, we reject the null hypo and conclude that the data is stationary.

Comment: what is meaning of 'Lags' in the table;
precisely how to decipher whether the series is stationary or not?